# Safari cuts off part of font in Revolution Slider

Tags: safari, revolution-slider

Safari is cutting off part of a font on my Revolution Slider:

http://st-tropezhome.com/

Chrome and Firefox display it fine but I'm only seeing the cut off in Safari and on my iphone...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the font you use in the slider.

Make sure that the font loaded well with all its font weight which is used in the slider and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I added a bit of padding to the font boxes in the styles and it worked great.